# Accessing min.us API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'd like to incorporate min.us galleries into something I'm making, yet I'm having trouble accessing their API.

An example of the JSON returned from a (picked at random from google) gallery:

http://min.us/api/GetItems/mvjf2eq

```
{"READ_ONLY_URL_FOR_GALLERY": "vjf2eq", "GALLERY_TITLE": "Hani Talaat", "ITEMS_GALLERY": ["http://i.min.us/jmwpdw.jpg", "http://i.min.us/jm0kae.jpg", "http://i.min.us/jmvLn8.jpg"]}
```

Both using ajax & getJSON I get the same error:

- **webkit** : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
- **Firebug** : invalid label

Here is what I've been trying:

```
$.getJSON(
  'http://min.us/api/GetItems/mvjf2eq?callback=?',
   function(data) {
     console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The API does not return JSONP, only JSON. I.e. jQuery expects JSONP but only gets JSON. You probably have to have a look again at the documentation of the API and check whether it supports JSONP or not. If not you cannot use it from JS.

Comment: Mr. Kling is right - it looks like that API is designed to be used from a server, because it's giving back just JSON without the JSONP function call wrapper.

Comment: Ah. Thank you.
I assumed because of this: https://github.com/buger/minus-javascript/blob/master/minus.js that there was a way to access it..   

May I ask - You inspected the header it was returning to determine that?

Comment: No, I just had a look at the response. JSONP looks like `funcName({...})`, whereas JSON is just the `{...}` part. I also had a look at the file you linked to, but it looks like they just get the JSON data and parse it. There is nothing indicating that the use JSONP. I assume this client does not work in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. JSONP is one way to workaround this limitation but the server must support it which doesn't seem to be the case from the url you have shown. A correctly returned JSONP response would look like this:

```
someCallbackName({"READ_ONLY_URL_FOR_GALLERY": "vjf2eq", "GALLERY_TITLE": "Hani Talaat", "ITEMS_GALLERY": ["http://i.min.us/jmwpdw.jpg", "http://i.min.us/jm0kae.jpg", "http://i.min.us/jmvLn8.jpg"]})
```

where the client has the possibility to define the callback name instead of the JSON object you are getting.